# Make a jQuery UI close with setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to make my jQuery UI dialog close after 5 seconds, but the code below doesn't do anything, any suggestions? I did test it with `alert("hellow")` and it did work fine but the code below is not working.

```
success: function(data) {

 $(data).dialog({

    modal: true,
    width: 900,
    height: 600,
    resizable: false,
    title: thetitle,
    draggable: false,
    open: function(event, ui) {
        setTimeout('$(this).dialog("close");', 5000);                   
  }
});
```

Why isn't this closing my dialog after 5 seconds? It does not do anything.

Answer (score 6):

You'll want to pass `setTimeout` an actual function, rather than a string.

```
setTimeout(function() { 
   $(data).dialog("close");
 }, 5000);
```

When you pass a string, the code is `eval`'d, which I'm pretty sure sets `this` to the global object (which is why `$(this).dialog` would never work).

Note that `this` won't with the above way either (since again `this` is the global object at that point), but it's still considered much, much better form than passing a string to `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 1):

What about jquery .delay()?

```
success: function(data) {

 $(data).dialog({

    modal: true,
    width: 900,
    height: 600,
    resizable: false,
    title: thetitle,
    draggable: false,
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).dialog("close").delay(5000);            
  }
});
```

Comment: you know what, don't call me an ignorant but i did not know the jQuery function delay(), it may help me solve and clean lots bad code in this project I am working on now. Thanks for taking the time to read my problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
var sT = setTimeout('$(this).dialog("close");', 5000);
```

Comment: thanks for the help but actually adam rackis was right but using this inside the settimeout function was the error. thanks a lot for the help